# Setting color for p:colorpicker programatically in popup mode

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am making a form for editing formatting values that are stored in a database. Two of these are colors and I am using the colorpicker from PrimeFaces.

However when I load the HEX color values from the DB and set them to the field the color picker is using as `value` it doesn't render properly.

There is no color in the popup button: [image]

even though the color is shown properly when I open the colorpicker: 
See: [image]

After clicking on the dot the popup button is shown correctly:
[image]

here is the code snippet I use for my colorPicker.

```
    <p:dialog>
      <p:outputLabel for="bgColor" value="#{msg.userASSettingsBackg}"/>
      <p:colorPicker id="bgColor" value="#{userASSettings.bgColor}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.userASSettingsColorError}"/> 
      <p:message for="bgColor" display="text"/>
    </p:dialog>
```

The dialog is opened using commandButton and menuItem from a dataTable.
in both cases I update the whole dialog.

Comment: Please state your PF version

Comment: @Kukeltje Using maven dependency on 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this issue was that the color value was saved in the DB as string and had the hashtag prefix for the color code.